# Add CRM 2013 workflow button back

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am woking on a CRM 2013 solution which is updated from previous CMR 2011 version. The Run Workflow and Dialog buttons has been removed. I tried to add them back by using Ribbon editor but they are not showing from the UI. I tried IIS reset and delete IE history. Here is the XML in the customizations.xml

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
    <CustomActions>
      <CustomAction Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.rdl_project.MainTab.Workflow.Controls._children" Sequence="10">
        <CommandUIDefinition>
          <Button Alt="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.Alt" Command="Mscrm.RunWorkflowSelected" Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/runworkflow32.png" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/StartWorkflow_16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.LabelText" Sequence="10" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CustomAction>
      <CustomAction Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.rdl_project.Related.Activities.Controls._children" Sequence="40">
        <CommandUIDefinition>
          <Button Alt="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.Alt" Command="Mscrm.RunWorkflowSelected" Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/runworkflow32.png" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/StartWorkflow_16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.LabelText" Sequence="40" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.ToolTipDescription" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CustomAction>
    </CustomActions>
    <Templates>
      <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
    </Templates>
    <CommandDefinitions />
    <RuleDefinitions>
      <TabDisplayRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <EnableRules />
    </RuleDefinitions>
    <LocLabels>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.Alt">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.LabelText">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run a workflow for this {0}. &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;View the status of workflows in the Workflow tab of this record." languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.Alt">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.LabelText">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.ToolTipDescription">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run a workflow for this {0}. &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;View the status of workflows in the Workflow tab of this record." languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
      <LocLabel Id="new.rdl_project.Button2.Button.ToolTipTitle">
        <Titles>
          <Title description="Run Workflow" languagecode="1033" />
        </Titles>
      </LocLabel>
    </LocLabels>
  </RibbonDiffXml>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid deleting any system buttons entirely. I think better approach is just to hide them. Using Visual Ribbon Editor it should not be even possible to delete them entirely. I assume you have deleted them by modifying RibbonDiffXml by hand at some point though and now you're trying to get them back using Visual Ribbon Editor (or Ribbon Workbench).

What I would do in this case is I would go and download Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK. In the SDK there's Resources\ExportedRibbonXml folder which contains RibbonDiffXml definations for all system entities that comes with CRM 2013. Probably you can just copy definitions from there the way you like.